# How to resolve instance with Autofac and Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have just started to try out Autofac and I think I am confusing myself with resolving the concrete classes.

I have managed to register my Interfaces to my Concrete classes as below

```
builder.RegisterType<TestClass>().As<ITest>();
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

This builds fine. The problem I am having is how to do get an instance of this in my mvc controller? Most things I have read say I need to create a new instance of ContainerBuilder and then call the scope.Resolve method, but surely this is bad practice and shouldnt be needed in each controller?

I think the confusion is when and how to access 'Container' so that I can call the resolve method as and when I need to.

Im a newbie at this as you have probably guessed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do it is use the controllers constructor as Autofac will handle this for you:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private ITest _test;

    public MyController(ITest test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use the constructor and let the dependency get injected for you, you can do this in your controller action method:

```
var test = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITest>()
```

Comment: Ok this looks good. So assuming I wanted to resolve a few dependencies in my controller in a particular action, I would have to use method 2 right?

Comment: Yes, though I prefer method 1 as it's much easier to test.

Comment: Yes Ive seen many people mention this is an anti-pattern. Can you use method 1 though with multiple dependencies?

Comment: Yes, you can pass as many parameters into your constructor as you like.

Comment: This all seems to be working well except when I try to create an instance of Identity. Im trying builder.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(); and trying to resolve this but I get an error 'The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.'